# Requisição na API do Twitter utilizando Jquery e Ajax

Tags: ajax, rest, twitter-api

Estou tentando buscar os dados de uma página do Twitter, sem sucesso até agora.
Consegui o token de acesso através do Controller PHP, e pretendo utiliza-lo para fazer requisições.

---

```
var token = 'Bearer <?php echo $token['twitter'] ?>';
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=<?php echo $empresa['twitter']?>",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    beforeSend : function( xhr ) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", token );
        xhr.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "My Twitter App v1.0.23");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
    },
}).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

---

Segundo o Twitter, a requisição deve conter os seguintes dados em seu cabeçalho:

> GET /1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=100&screen_name=twitterapi HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: api.twitter.com
>
> User-Agent: My Twitter App v1.0.23
>
> Authorization: Bearer AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA%2FAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA%3DAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip

Para comfirmar se o problema não era a chave, implementei a chamada em PHP, e tudo funcionou perfeitamente.

Quando acesso a página que comporta o script, ocorre a chamada e o erro 401 é retornado. Segundo o Twitter:

> 401    Unauthorized

O cabeçalho que está sendo inserido na chamada Ajax é o mesmo que foi inserido em PHP, então qual o problema?